# Display flex acting differently in Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, flexbox

**Background:**
In a tool my team is working on, we are implementing a `header` that moves off the screen programmatically based on an event listener. After writing the first implementation it worked as expected but only in Chrome.

I am using `display:flex` on the `#wrapper` as well as on the `#content` elements.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>Header Content</header>
   ...
      <section id="content">
        <div id="subcontent">
          <div id="tool">
            <div id="tool-container"></div>
            <svg id="svgTool" height="100%" width="100%" class="svgTool style-scope test-tool"></svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
   ...
</div>
```

some of the css:

```
...
#wrapper {
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  min-height:100%;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
...
```

Using some simple JavaScript I am adjusting the `margin-top` of the `header` element when a button is clicked (for this example).

**Problem:** While Chrome works as expected, Safari does not. I suspect that this must be due to how Safari's version of webkit interprets elements using `display: flex`. *edit: or perhaps it is due to how Safari works with `vh` units?*

In Chrome the header will slide up and down without affecting the `<svg>` element. In Safari, adjusting the `margin-top` of the header will cause the `svg` element to create whitespace on the bottom of the screen equal to change in the `header`'s `margin-top`.

**JSBin:**
This JSbin works identically to the current implementation of our tool.
Open it both in Chrome and Safari to see the discrepancy.

http://jsbin.com/kaxiqig/edit?html,css,output

<sub>sidenote: firefox also works as expected</sub>

Comment: You might be dealing with https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#11-min-and-max-size-declarations-are-ignored-when-wrapping-flex-items

Comment: when i click "test slide" in chrome, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @MichaelCoker do you have "auto-run js" enabled in jsbin?

Comment: @captainrad that's it. I don't use jsbin very often. You should include this code in your post here on SO, too. jsbin isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: FWIW, I see the same problems in Safari even if I switch all `vh` units to percents. So not sure it's related to the units. That said, you can fix this by toggling a `min-height` on `main` while you're also toggling the header margin. Is the goal just to avoid that for simplicity, or will that work?

Comment: What if you use `transform: translate` instead, either initially positioned off screen and then moved into view, or the other way around

Comment: @cjl750 I'll give that a shot. Thanks.

Comment: @LGSon, that is a solution that "works" but in this use case I believe it will cause unexpected side-effects based on the actual content of the svg.. (maybe.. I will have to try it)

Comment: @cjl750 That solution is sufficient! If you want to answer this with an explanation of why/how it works I will mark it as answered. Thanks!

Comment: @captainrad Great! See answer below now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lieu of a real fix for what seems to be a bug, a simple workaround is to toggle the height of `main` while you are also toggling the header position. Basically, it seems that Safari is pulling `main` up with the header as it transitions upwards, so we'll just make it taller so it extends down to the bottom of the screen again.

The default height of `main` is `calc(100vh - 80px)`, so we can just modify the second half of that calc expression to get our new value. Exactly how you modify it depends on how tall the header is in your application. Let's say that in this case the header is typically 100px tall. Since the header is transitioned to be `margin-top: -75px`, we can just change our calc expression to `calc(100vh - 25px)` for the new height.

While I initially suggested toggling a `minimum-height` on `main`, I noticed that we also get an ugly bug when doing that where the minimum height change doesn't quite transition right even if we add a matching transition property, leaving a white gap at the bottom of the screen for a split second. So we can just animate the actual `height` instead, which gives a nice smooth result.

In your CSS, I added this line:

```
main {
  transition: height .5s;
}
```

The new sliding function becomes:

```
function slide() {
  if (document.querySelector('header').style.marginTop !== "-75px") {
    document.querySelector('header').style.transition = ".5s";
    document.querySelector('header').style.marginTop = "-75px";
    document.querySelector('main').style.height = "calc(100vh - 25px)";
  } else {
    document.querySelector('header').style.marginTop = "0";
    document.querySelector('main').style.height = "";
  }
}
```

If your header is going to vary in height, you can either toggle a class on `main` instead, and revise the calc expression that class uses with different media queries, or you could enhance the function to first find the viewport height and then subtract the post-transition header height to find the new height to apply to `main`.